# WPF Save Photo Effect

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, save, effect

So I have the code to save the image i edited with drop shadow for example and after i save i find out that the code only saves the file with the size of the image.What i need is to either save with the new size with the effect on(the image should get larger in size because of the shadow underneath it for example).
I dont know how to edit the code to save a larger image.If the image is staticly larger its really no problem i dont mind if it saves the size of the image + 20 pixel on each size for example.

```
try
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
    saveDialog.Filter = "JPeg Image(*.JPG)|*.jpg|Bitmap Image(*.BMP)|*.bmp|Png Image(*.PNG)|*.png|Gif Image(*.GIF)|*.gif";
    if (saveDialog.ShowDialog().Value == true)
    {
        // Save current canvas transform
        Transform transform = image1.LayoutTransform;
        // reset current transform (in case it is scaled or rotated)
        image1.LayoutTransform = null;

        // Get the size of canvas
        Size size = new Size(image1.ActualWidth, image1.ActualHeight);
        // Measure and arrange the surface
        // VERY IMPORTANT
        image1.Measure(size);
        image1.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
          new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)size.Width,
            (int)size.Height,
            96d,
            96d,
            PixelFormats.Default);
        renderBitmap.Render(image1);
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        string extension = saveDialog.FileName.Substring(saveDialog.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
        switch (extension.ToLower())
        {
            case ".jpg":
                encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                break;
            case ".bmp":
                encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                break;
            case ".gif":
                encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
                break;
            case ".png":
                encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                break;
        }
        // push the rendered bitmap to it
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
        // Create a file stream for saving image
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(saveDialog.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            encoder.Save(fs);
        }
        // Restore previously saved layout
        image1.LayoutTransform = transform;
    }

}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `FileMode.Create` instead of `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` in the call to `System.IO.File.Open()`

Comment: i changed it but still that did not solve my problem...i dont know why it would have

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you added a "bitmap effect" or "shader" to the image in WPF, the outcome is to be expected as these aren't part of the layouting process and aren't factored into the "ActualWidth/ActualHeight". You could add a few units in the creation of the new image:

```
Size size = new Size(image1.ActualWidth + 20, image1.ActualHeight + 20);
```

If the other layout properties of the "image1" object are correct, this should do the trick.

EDIT: I recommend using a new control to render the image and not use a control that is part of a different visual tree already. The layouting/rendering might have all sorts of weird side effects. Here's a piece of code that worked for the drop shadow effect:

EDIT 2: set the "Effect" property to the same object as in the UI...

```
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            saveDialog.Filter = "JPeg Image(*.JPG)|*.jpg|Bitmap Image(*.BMP)|*.bmp|Png Image(*.PNG)|*.png|Gif Image(*.GIF)|*.gif";
            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog().Value == true)
            {
                Image image2 = new Image();
                image2.Source = image1.Source;
                Grid container = new Grid();
                container.Children.Add(image2);
                container.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                image2.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                image2.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                image2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

                // Get the size of canvas
                Size size = new Size(image2.Source.Width + 20, image2.Source.Height + 20);
                // Measure and arrange the surface
                // VERY IMPORTANT
                container.Measure(size);
                container.Arrange(new Rect(size));

                // BitmapEffect is deprecated and buggy, use Effect instead.

                // since the effect isn't part of the visual tree but independent,
                // we can just reuse the same object as on the image in the UI.
                image2.Effect = image1.Effect;

                //image2.Effect = new DropShadowEffect
                //{
                //    Color = Colors.Black,
                //    ShadowDepth = 5,
                //    BlurRadius = 3,
                //    Opacity = 1
                //};


                // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
                RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
                  new RenderTargetBitmap(
                    (int)size.Width,
                    (int)size.Height,
                    96d,
                    96d,
                    PixelFormats.Default);

                renderBitmap.Render(container);
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                string extension = saveDialog.FileName.Substring(saveDialog.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                switch (extension.ToLower())
                {
                    case ".jpg":
                        encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                        break;
                    case ".bmp":
                        encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                        break;
                    case ".gif":
                        encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
                        break;
                    case ".png":
                        encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                        break;
                }
                // push the rendered bitmap to it
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
                // Create a file stream for saving image
                using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(saveDialog.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Also, is there a reason why you use the clipboard to load the image?

Comment: I tryed what you recomended and ended up with this(note if i try with 20 on both the aqua line on right is smaller but its still just that line : http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/5682/ko7h.jpg the black lines apear always in the saved files except on PNG format.

Comment: It is hard to predict the outcome without knowing exactly how "image1" is constructed and how it ties in with the rest of the application. The black is the "background color" of the new image - which is invisible in PNG since it will be "transparent" there. Depending on the context of image1 there are multiple ways of filling the new image with white (or any other color) before rendering the image.

Comment: well what i was looking for was just the picture with the outer glow effect around it.

Comment: I got that much - but you have to understand that bitmaps (PNG/JPG..) don't have "effects"only pixels. The outer glow effect adds to the outside of the image. So it can only be applied by the viewing application or it has to be part of the image itself. And if it is part of the image, the "background" it operates against has to be part of the image as well. I.e. white background, image + drop shadow on white background. The JPG output looks weird because up until the save operation, WPF will work with semi-transparent pixels that become opaque when saved. Can you share the code for "image1"?

Comment: <Image Height="246" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,53,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" ImageFailed="image1_ImageFailed" /> this is the XAML code because on c# code there is nothing.

Comment: Updated my answer after trying out some variations.

Comment: this almost worked as it ended up looking like this:http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/2800/7xe5.jpg notice that no matter what effect i use it ends up like this.So if i use blur (that worked before it still looks like this).even the outer glow looks like this now

Comment: oh wait i just took a look at the code and noticed that you put the effect in the code.at my program i have 3 buttons and the effects happend when i press the button not when i save can you adjust for this please :D?

Comment: if i try to save without that effect it saves without the efect and  an empty space around it